# Estou utilizando o c++ com a biblioteca da openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Estou utilizando o c++ com a biblioteca da openGL, estou com um pouco de dificuldade na criação de um método. Preciso criar uns prédios randomicamente, mas para não criar um dentro do outro eu preciso comparar os 4 pontos do prédio. Se alguém puder me ajudar.

```
string localizacaoPredio[150];
int ultimaPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
    int x = rand() % 10 + 1;
    int z = rand() % 10 + 1;
    string coordenada = x + ";" + z;

    for (int j = 0; j < ultimaPos; j++){
        if (localizacaoPredio[j].compare(coordenada)){
            x = rand() % 10 + 1;
            z = rand() % 10 + 1;
            coordenada = x + ";" + z;
            j = -1;
        }
    }
    localizacaoPredio[ultimaPos] = coordenada;
    ultimaPos++;
}
int andares[150];
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
    andares[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
}
int numDivisoes[150];
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){
    numDivisoes[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++){

    Building b1(localizacaoPredio[i], y1, andares[i], numDivisoes[i], 1, 1);
    planos.push_back(b1.predio[0].plano);
    planos.push_back(b1.predio[1].plano);
    planos.push_back(b1.predio[2].plano);
    planos.push_back(b1.predio[3].plano);
    planos.push_back(b1.predio[4].plano);
    city.push_back(b1);
}
```

Comment: Olá, bem vinda ao SOPT. Muita gente pode te ajudar. Basta vc fazer uma pergunta. Comece pelo [tour], depois leia [ask], e finalmente volte aqui e edite a questão para de fato perguntar algo objetivo sobre a sua dificuldade (é sobre compilação? é sobre aleatoridade? é sobre desenho de formas? é sobre detecção de inclusão de um prédio no outro? etc).

Comment: Olá, Luiz. É o seguinte, eu preciso criar um vetor ou um array, para a criação de prédios, mas para que nenhum fique em cima do outro eu preciso comparar com todos os anteriores. Eu ainda estou meio confusa com a pergunta, eu não tô muito familiarizada com o c++ e tô me batendo nesse método.

Comment: Eu entendi. Mas ainda assim a sua pergunta não é suficientemente clara. Por exemplo, o significado *informal* de "em cima" pode variar considerando que se trata de uma aplicação 3D. Por exemplo, pode querer dizer "dentro" (isto é, a fundação de um prédio não pode coincidir com a fundação de outro); ou pode querer dizer "na frente" (isto é, um prédio não pode obstruir a visão de outro a partir da câmera;

Comment: Eu suponho que você deseje algo no sentido do primeiro entendimento (isto é, não quer que prédios ocupem o mesmo espaço físico). Supondo que vc já sabe desenhar o prédio e que os prédios são todos polígonos regulares, o problema seria somente não permitir que as fundações se sobreponham, certo? Vc já tentou algo comparando as coordenadas dos eixos x e y de cada par de prédio? Se sim, poste o seu código.

Comment: Quando eu crio os prédios eu saio do ponto x e y, mas como o prédio é um polígono, ele tem a criação de mais 3 pontos, e quando eu faço a verificação se esta se sobrepondo, eu só consigo verificar no primeiro ponto que eu criei.

Comment: Eu não sei como envio o bloco de código aqui

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código nela. Veja aqui como formatar código: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1599/formatar-c%c3%b3digo-nas-respostas-do-stack-overflow

Comment: Olá, eu editei o código